# echoing a variable

Tags: php

I'm making a search engine, and one of the features will be that it searches Google, among other things.  The first thing I did was find out how to generate a Google search based on URL alone.  Well, "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1542&bih=928&q=" is the first part, "Query" is the second part, and "&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&qscrl=1" is the third part.  Now, on the client-side I made a form I called "search", and the action was the file below.  However, my attempts to make this plausible on server-side have failed completely.  Below is the code:

```
    <?php

  $something = $_REQUEST["search"];
  $txt1="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1542&bih=928&q=";
  $txt2 = $something;
  $txt3="&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&qscrl=1";
  $string=$txt1.$txt2."+".$txt3;

  $link_to_dig = $string;

  $original_file = @file_get_contents($link_to_dig);
  if(!$original_file)
    die("Error loading {$link_to_dig}");

  $path_info = parse_url($link_to_dig);
  $base = $path_info['scheme'] . "://" . $path_info['host'];

  $stripped_file = strip_tags($original_file, "<a>");
  $fixed_file = preg_replace("/<a([^>]*)href=\"\//is", "<a$1href=\"{$base}/", $stripped_file);
  $fixed_file = preg_replace("/<a([^>]*)href=\"\?/is", "<a$1href=\"{$link_to_dig}/?", $fixed_file);
  preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $fixed_file, $matches);

  //DEBUGGING


  //$matches[0] now contains the complete A tags; ex: <a href="link">text</a>
  //$matches[1] now contains only the HREFs in the A tags; ex: link

  $result = print_r($matches, true);
  $result = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $result);
  print "<pre>" . $result . "</pre>";

?>
```

Thanks for helping!

This is the form:

```
<form class="searchengine" name="search" action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" style="width:580px; height:35px; color:#000000;" class="search" name="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: To specify, when I said that "Query" was the second part, I meant that as a general, "insert query here" type of thing

Comment: "However, my attempts to make this plausible on client-side have failed completely" - How? Why?

Comment: whoops, I meant server-side.  I just fixed that

Comment: You'll need to post the code for your search for too so we can make sure it's correctly sending the data back.

Comment: Accessing google like this places you in violation of section 5.3 of their terms of service: http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're very new to php and have gotten this script from somewhere and trying to modify it to fit.

[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) - Output one or more strings - No value is returned.

So:

```
$txt2 = echo "$something"
```

First off it fails because there is no ending semicolon.

Is printing $something to the screen, and $txt is being set to nothing.

You do already have the value in $something, so I don't know why you'd want to change it to another variable, but this will do it:

```
$txt2 = $something;
```

Then if you want to make the script nicer, the majority of people on SO will point you towards [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: actually yeah, I am new to php.  nonetheless, I really would like to know how to piece together $txt1, $txt2, and $txt3 to make http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1542&bih=928&q=Query+&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&qscrl=1

Comment: @Matthew its in the answer... replace `$txt2 = echo "$something"` with  `$txt2 = $something;`. Its a very basic part of PHP though, might be worth working on some simple examples to first understand the language.

Comment: I recognize my mistake, but when I plugged it back into my site, it told me that I had an unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 5

Comment: @Matthew Your code must be different to what you have posted... Are you sure you include the semicolon?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my question and inserted a semi-colon, got rid of the echo bit, and then edited my webpage and did the same thing.

Comment: @Matthew the error you're getting doesn't correspond to the code you've posted.

Comment: I guess that just shows my inexperience, doesn't it?  For some reason, a character didn't copy when I copied it into Notepad.  It works fine now.  Thanks for helping, but sorry for all the trouble!